# Puse Relative Layout y se me pegó todo arriba

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Ya tenia mi app listo y puse relative layout para probar que tal y ahora no deja mover las cosas, aparte que todo se fue hacia arriba, lo queria probar ya que menciona que asi es más facil para la adaptación de pantalla de diferentes dispositivos pero lo lei tarde ya cuando la app estaba listo

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="415dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@color/TomarHora"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Si necesita retiro de productos, retiro de exámenes, consulta o control"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo queria probar que tal D: pero todo se junto y no me deja sacar los diferentes elemtnos de ahi, si podrian darme una mano con ese tema

Comment: `RelativeLayout` ha sido practicamente deprecado desde hace un buen tiempo. Si quieres que sea más fácil lo de la adaptación de la pantalla a diferentes dispositivos, deberías probar el `ConstraintLayout`. De hecho, veo que uno de tus `TextView` ya utiliza constrains.

Comment: Que lo usaba antes con constrains pero el tema es que con el Relative se adaptaba más a las diferentes pantallas, con el constrain no me las adaptaba, ya solucioné el error igualmente

Comment: Deberías de usar ConstraintLayout. Te permite arrastrar y soltar elementos, en lugar de editar el XML. Es similar a RelativeLayout, si buscas que se adapte a todos los dispositivos. [Documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

Usando la propiedad layout_below en RelativeLayout puedes poner una vista debajo de otra

```
   android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
```

Aqui te dejare tu ejemplo a tu pregunta, recuerda cambiar los colores.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Blanco">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="415dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/Blanco"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Si necesita retiro de productos, retiro de exámenes, consulta o control"
        android:textColor="@color/Negro"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```